# Find a function such that $f^{(i)}(x)=i,i=1,2,\cdots,n.$

Tags: calculus, functions

Give $n$-th derivatives, can we find a function ?
For example, if $f^{(i)}(x)=i,i=1,2,\cdots,n.$ , can we construct a function such that it satisfies the condition.
It just occurs in my mind. I didn't know if it has a solution.

Comment: If you need $f(z)$ with $f^{(i)}(x)=i$ for $i\in\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ (just at $z=x$ with _fixed_ $x$), the Taylor series gives you $$f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i(z-x)^i}{i!}=(z-x)e^{z-x}.$$

Comment: As you can see, no one understands what _do_ you _really_ mean.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for a function $f$, such that
$$f'=1$$
$$f''=2$$
$$f'''=3$$
$$...$$
But if $f'$ is a constant, then $f''=0$ (and so are all higher derivatives), so no such function can exist.

I suppose we can't rule out functions with domains/codomains other than the Real numbers without a little more work, but we'd still need $f$ to be differentiable.

Am I answering the right question?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is such that it satisfies this condition. In particular, this implies that $f^{(1)}(x)=1$ for all $x$ and hence $f^{(2)}(x)=0$ for all $x$, a contradiction. So, such an $f$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If $f^{(i)}(x)=i$, then $f^{(i-1)}(x)=ix+k=i-1$, so this could work for specific values of $x$, but it will not hold in general

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are asking if we can always construct a function such that its first derivative is equal to the constant function $x \mapsto 1$ , it second derivative equal to $ x \mapsto 2 $, etc.

Well this is impossible because if for a given $n$ we have $f^{(n)} = x \mapsto n $ then the derivative of this function would be identically zero. And then $f^{(n-1)}$ would be a polynomial and not a constant function equal to $n-1$

Otherwise if you were wondering if we can always find a function such that $f^{(n)} = x \mapsto n $ for a unique n, then the answer is yes and is any polynomial of degree $n$ such that the highest monomial is $\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$ for instance.